# Android app rejection reasons

Tags: android, google-play

please anyone guide me for the steps to consider to avoid rejection of android applications at app store

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that you mean Android Market and not Apple's app store (where I imagine every Android app would be rejected), then you simply need to conform to the [Developer Program Policies](http://www.android.com/us/developer-content-policy.html) and [Developer Distribution Agreement](http://www.android.com/us/developer-distribution-agreement.html).

Comment: LoL.. I didn't see an iPhone tag in his question, means he meant android market only! :)

Comment: @Sheikh - You're right - no iPhone tag. It was just that I couldn't resist making some comment when I saw the android tag and "app store" in the same post. :)

Comment: haha.. yeah I had guessed that.. just wanted to add some more spice to it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Android apps don't go through an approval process, first thing.
Secondly, there are some things your app shouldn't be doing to avoid being killed by Google. For example, your app shouldn't contain the following things:

- Explicit(Vulgar) content
- Violence
- Hate Speech
- Impersonation
- Stealing personal information
- Gambling

**UPDATE**

Ohh, Ted has already posted a nice answer. please follow those links.